# Could I use "zu … von" to ask the difference between two objects?

Tags: expression, comparison

I was watching a German YouTuber asking the difference of normal pork and a special raw minced pork, and he said something too fast that was hard for me to grasp, but it sounds like:

> Was ist der Unterschied zum Hackfleisch von normalen?

I was thinking that the expression could be:

> Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Hackfleisch und normalen Fleisch.

Not sure if I heard it correctly, but do native German speakers use "zu … von …" to express differences between two things/objects?

Comment: Just the other way round: In colloquial German you could hear Was ist der Unterschied _von_ Hackfleisch _zu_ normalem Fleisch?

Comment: I see, it was a little bit fast and I just hope to make sure how he expressed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To describe the difference between two objects one can use:

"Der Unterschied **von** ... **zu** ..."

or

"Der Unterschied **zwischen** ... **und** ..."

Comment: Is it possible to switch the positions of "von" and "zu" like in the post? Perhaps in daily/colloquial speech?

Comment: @Marses No you can't change the position of "von" and "zu".